# Protractor: Select available date from datepicker else go next month and select?

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, protractor, gulp-protractor

I'm new to Protractor and here I'm trying to test an date picker from Protractor.

I tried to `this.selectAvailableDate = element(by.css('td[aria-disabled="false"]'));`

this will select date from current month ,**What I need  if date is not available in current month then click next month icon and see there**

If someone know how to test please help.
Thanks in advance :)
[this](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) is the datepicker and in my code some dates are disabled due to requirement 
anyone can help?

Comment: We will definitely need at least the HTML representation of the date-picker, or a way to reproduce your problem. What kind of a datepicker this is and is it available online to interact with?

Comment: @alecxe I just added in description, please check, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar case and solved it like this:

```js
var endDate = element(by.css("owl-date-time[ng-reflect-name=targetEnd]"));
endDate.click();
endDate.element(by.css(".icon-owl-right-open")).click();
endDate.element(by.css(".icon-owl-right-open")).click(); // Just go 2 Months to the Future

endDate.element(by.css(".owl-day")).click();
```

It is not pretty because you have to get the specific css for the little arrows in the datepicker, but then you can be sure to hit a valid date (for me it had to be in the future and I didn't want to make it too complex). Maybe this helps in your case as well :)